# how to open link for external page in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

i have project a dictionary use phonegap and jquery mobile, my project in the field are: description, pictures, videos in the form of links from youtube. Here I want to ask how I could open link from youtube using the application youtube in my android device?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function myFunction() {
    window.open('https://youtu.be/d9JWQcVrLpY', '_blank', 'location=no')
}
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but there is no change, this javascript code detail of my project.